# Different letter-spacing for different fonts

Tags: javascript, css

I have set a letter-spacing for a webpage that fits perfectly to my needs, the texts look good and are easy to read; however, I have set Arial as a backup font just in case the browser used doesn´t accept embedded fonts, but when using Arial the letter-spacing messes everything up and overflows.

Is there a way in css or js to set a letter spacing for the first choice in font-family and a different letter spacing for the second choice? Effectively it would mean asking the browser which font it is using and setting a different letter-spacing depending on if it uses the first or second font.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Cant you detect when the fall-back font is being used with JavaScript and just set the letter-spacing dynamically?

Comment: If you’d need to change letter spacing just because the natural spacing of a font breaks your layout, or “everything,” then it’s the design that needs fixing, not the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Answer (score 0):

For every custom font, there is probably a cross-browser fall-back font that almost looks the same in line-height and letter-spacing.

What i want to explain is that you could set a different font as fall-back, like Verdana or so, that could match the letter spacing without messing things up.

Comment: What you suggest may be good if the site have only one language. But when you have a paragraph that has words in two languages in it (for example the main text is in **Persian language** and there are some **English words** in it), We need a method to define "different" letter-spacing for each font (I mean the main font and the fallback font ). Is there any method to do that without the need to use extra "span" tags for each English word in the main text?